# Weird PhpStorm quotes behavior

Tags: ide, phpstorm, quotes, quote

I've just recently updated my PhpStorm to version 8.0.3 and I've noticed a weird and rather annoying behavior when placing single or double quotes.

When I place a quote it gets underlined (img: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wjWuB.png) and when I try to write further it skips one letter, for example: I write a quote and try write a word:hello, what gets written - 'ello, when it should have been - 'hello.

How can I disable/fix this feature/bug?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Your OS? Share your `idea.log` file please (Help | Show Log in...)

Comment: I'm using OS X v10.10.3, and log: http://p.smx.lt/HPuMk0N

Comment: Unfortunately I was unable to find any related tickets myself. Suggestions: 1) File a ticket at [Issue Tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI) with log attached; 2) Please try v9 EAP build http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Early+Access+Program

Comment: So I turned-off my mac and left it overnight and this bug seems to be gone now. Will definitely try your suggestion if this happens again tho, thanks for the help.